# Home page slider not working in chrome or safari

Tags: jquery, slider

I am trying to implement a one page slider to a homepage and I have it working in FF and IE but not in safari or Chrome..

This is the code I am using for the slider..

```
//sliding content
$("#main-nav a").click(function(){ 
    var target = $(this).attr("href"); 
    $("html, body").stop().animate({  
        scrollLeft: $(target).offset().left,  
     }, 1200);  
});
```

The url of the site in question is http://stable.dev.lemon-fresh.co.uk

Comment: done.. :) what wat the answer just use $(target).offset().left? as it is gone.. Could you go into a little depth? Cheers.. Danny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!
use `position` instead of `offset`:
 `scrollLeft: $(target).position().left`

And remove the comma '`,`' as you are not listing any other properties.

```
$("#main-nav a").click(function(){ 
    var target = $(this).attr("href"); 
    $("html, body").stop(1).animate({  // used : .stop(1) (same as .stop(true) )
        scrollLeft: $(target).position().left  // position instead of offset
     }, 1200);  
});
```

**And another suggestion:**

As I have seen, on fast-clicking on your links - all the animations gets cached resulting in an annoying waiting to get to the right place. A nice trick to remove (clear) that animation queue is to use `.stop(1)` try it out!